# How can I make a Perl script executable from everywhere by everyone?

Tags: perl, executable

I wrote a very simple perl script, and now I want to make it executable from everywhere.

I know I could just drop it into /bin/, rename it from 'mytest.pl' -> 'mytest', and chmod +x, but is this standard practice? I noticed nothing in /bin/ is a perl script.

Also, I want it to be able to log to /var/logs/mytest/*

Are there any security issues I should be aware of?

Comment: to make it look more professional! like /usr/bin/cpan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is preferable to put user-made scripts in /usr/local/bin , but it's your call whether it's worth worrying about this.  As far as logging to /var/logs/mytest/*, you can try to make the script [suid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) (this is sometimes not allowed for security) with a user that can write to the dir, or just make /var/logs/mytest world-writable.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I found a whole bunch of perl scripts in there and I'm now following their lead.

Comment: Some systems may need the `perlsuid` executable in order to run a Perl script with setuid privileges.  `perlsuid` might not be installed by default (Debian splits it out into its own extra package (http://packages.debian.org/perl-suid) which isn't depended on) and has been deprecated in favor of using other mechanisms like `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of worrying about log file permissions issues, why not log to the system logger? That's what it's there for. See [Sys::Syslog](http://perldoc.perl.org/Sys/Syslog.html)